# SQL Server Stored Procedure Error on Insert using TRY CATCH

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wrote a stored procedure which uses encryption algorithm to insert a row into a  table. The procedure is executing successfully, but no row is added.

My code:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[User]
(
    UserID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Email NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    PasswordHash BINARY(64) NOT NULL,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(40) NULL,
    LastName NVARCHAR(40) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_User_UserID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserID ASC)
)

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.addUser
    @pEmail NVARCHAR(64), 
    @pPassword NVARCHAR(64), 
    @pFirstName NVARCHAR(40) = NULL, 
    @pLastName NVARCHAR(40) = NULL,
    @responseMessage NVARCHAR(250) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO dbo.[User] (Email, PasswordHash, FirstName, LastName)
        VALUES(@pEmail, HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @pPassword), @pFirstName, @pLastName)

        SET @responseMessage = 'Success'
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @responseMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE() 
    END CATCH
END

DECLARE @responseMessage NVARCHAR(250)
EXEC dbo.addUser
          @pEmail = 'Admin',
          @pPassword = '123',
          @pFirstName = 'Admin',
          @pLastName = 'Administrator',
          @responseMessage=@responseMessage OUTPUT
```

After executing the procedure, no rows have been added to the table.

Comment: What is the value of `@responseMessage` after execution? Also, if this is the setup for storing actual passwords this way, this is not a secure solution.

Comment: Don't return errors in output parameters.  Remove the @responseMessage parameter and the catch block and you should see the error.

Comment: hello @akshay, as per above sp it is working fine for me & data also added in table [User]. Have you checked further more ??

Comment: now its working fine. Thank you for help